# QGIS substring only working on first part of multipart line

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, grass-gis, vector, line

I am trying to extract part of a line starting at x meters and finishing at y meters of it's length. The problem is that if I use the "Line Substring" tool, it only works on the first part of the line. In this example, I wanted to extract a substring from 0 to 30 Km:

[image]

The documentation says the following about "Line Substring":

> If a multipart geometry is encountered, only the first part is considered when calculating the substring.

How can I manipulate my line so that it works correctly with "Line Substring"?

Comment: Have you tried dissolving the lines first? You might need some attribute to dissolve by though

Comment: It works! I used the Dissolve tool and selected all the fields. Thanks BERA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Dissolving first to close the gaps between lines. Then execute Line Substring on the dissolved lines.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Dissolve tool and selected all the fields. Now it seems to work correctly.